# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 installed but not appearing as a Provider for SQL 2008R2

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2, oledb, openrowset

I've installed Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 on a Windows7 machine but it doesn't appear under Providers in the relevant bit of the Registry `(HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER/Providers)` and, presumably because of this, doesn't appear in the list of Providers in the Linked Servers section of SQLServer Management Studio.

The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to run an `OPENROWSET` query against an Excel spreadsheet.

This is after I migrated my web application/database from XP to a new Windows 7 installation.

Needless to say everything was fine on the XP box.

Comment: Setting up ACE on a 64 bits machine combined with 32 bits applications can be a serious headache (am I right in assuming that your XP was 32 bits and the 7 is 64 bits?), see some references to related questions in the right column.

Comment: You never had an answer for this right? I'm having the same problem.